# Unable to link C runtime library (libcmt.lib) using lld-link.exe (Windows)

Tags: clang, llvm, msvcrt, crt, lld

I'm writing a language using LLVM. I'd like to avoid having to package clang and simply use the LLVM tools (ex. lld, lld-link). I've been trying to invoke the `printf` function from my simple IR code (`testinput.ll`):

```
; ModuleID = 'Test2'
source_filename = "entry"

@str_0 = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"Hello world!\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %anonymous_10 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @str_0, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 1234
}
```

But I keep receiving errors no matter what I try:

```
$ clang-cl -fuse-ld=lld-link testinput.ll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\spectre\x64\libcmt.lib"
```

Note: I've chosen the link randomly "... spectre\x64\libcmt.lib ..." by simply searching for `libcmt.lib` on the system.

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link: warning: libcmt.lib(loadcfg.obj): undefined symbol: __enclave_config
error: link failed
clang-cl.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Windows 10 (x64) with LLVM 5.0. Interestingly, using `link.exe` (Windows' VS tools' linker) everything works fine (which is what clang uses under the hood in my case).

I've read in [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24c20c20-6893-4605-8d1e-7481129bdea0/unresolved-externals-with-vs-2017):

> ... As I wrote earlier, __enclave_config is a variable that is filled in by the linker, but you have to use the VC linker, and a linker new enough to be able to automatically fill it in. ...

I believe the problem here is `libcmt.lib` and the `lld-link` linker. Is the `lld-link` version (LLVM 5.0) incompatible with the `libcmt.lib` that I'm using, is that the problem?

**Edit**: I've managed to track down what clang does behind the scenes, and have found it using the following command:

```
lld-link -out:a.exe -defaultlib:libcmt "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.17763.0\\um\\x64" -nologo "test.obj"
```

Clearly it's using lld-link, and it's working. However, strangely enough, it only compiles without errors if the input object file was compiled to .LL (LLVM IR) using clang (maybe using `-fuse-ld=lld -v` options?).

What's weird about this, is that upon inspection of the output .LL file from clang (`test.ll`) the full, source code (in IR) definitions of printf (and some other *printf functions used by it) is present (in the output .LL file).

So, somehow it's getting the definitions of `printf` itself inside the output .LL, IR code file.

As far as I know, you can't just `$ llc libcmt.lib testinput.ll`? That'd be the linker's job... (llc accepts only one positional argument)

The error that I'm getting once I try the same lld-link command and arguments with **my** `testinput.ll` file (not outputted from clang) is the following:

```
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: _mainCRTStartup
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: _printf
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, it was much much more simple than I anticipated. Maybe if the errors were at least somewhat helpful, I could have avoided all this confusion...

I've figured it out by comparing clang's output LL file, and noticed a curious line at the beginning:

```
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
```

Once I added it to my `testinput.ll` file, everything worked flawlessly with `lld-link`. Hurray!