# How to pass linker script from command line using clang on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, linker, clang, linker-scripts

I am using Windows OS, and the clang version is 8.0.0. I have installed visual studio community.

I am trying on linker scripts for custom memory mapping for one of my programs.

I am compiling and executing a program from the command line.
These are the option I tried on windows

```
clang main.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-Tlinker.ld -o main
```

Error Thrown was:

> ```
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/T'; ignored
> linker.ld : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x76
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1107 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

When I Tried with `-fuse-ld=lld-link` ,the error was different

```
lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -Tlinker.ld
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I want to know why the

> same commands work on ubuntu but not on windows?

And also kindly let me know the solution to pass linker scripts.

Is there any  command for clang on windows which should take linker scripts and clang linker `lld-link` at the same time?

Comment: I don't have the community edition of VS to try, so can't give an answer. I will make an observation - It almost looks as if CLANG in VS Community is using the Microsoft Linker which instead of `lld` (the error output seems to be that of the MS linker). The Microsoft Linker doesn't support linker scripts.

Comment: Are you using VS 2019 Community?

Comment: What happens if you add the `-fuse-ld=lld-link` option?

Comment: yes VS 2019. I will try with -fuse-ld=lld-link

Comment: I tried with lld-link and error was ```lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -Tlinker.ld
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Comment: I wont be able to execute the executable generated ```main```. It is leading into ```segmentation fault```

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Visual Studio help with clang-cl

```
clang-cl   options files  -fuse-ld=lld-link -v
```

-v                      Show commands to run and use verbose output

**-fuse-ld=lld-link**  use ld linker lld-link  for Windows

**-fuse-ld=lld**  use ld linker ld.lld  for Linux

```
cmake -E env LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld-link" PATH="<path\to\ninja>" 
  cmake -H. -G Ninja -Bbuild 
     -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" 
     -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" 
     -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID="Clang" 
     -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID="Clang" 
     -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Generic"
```

[LLVM Windows Linker support](https://lld.llvm.org/windows_support.html)

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Linker options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=vs-2019)

[cmake, ninja, clang-cl on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553436/building-with-cmake-ninja-and-clang-on-windows)

[Clang-cl manual on Windows](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#windows)

[LLVM extensions for LLD and clang-cl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LLVMExtensions.llvm-toolchain)

[(solved) research on ld-link with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160307/unable-to-link-c-runtime-library-libcmt-lib-using-lld-link-exe-windows)

I've figured it out by comparing clang's output LL file, and noticed a curious line at the beginning:

> target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"    add to  .LL file

Once I added it to my `testinput.ll` file, everything worked flawlessly with `lld-link`. Hurray!